# 'Pop-up' View animation

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to work out how to copy this 'pop-up' view animation shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBtcC.jpg. I am using this current code to show my viewController but currently only have a fade animation working. How can I create this animation shown? Is this custom?

```
   let popup : SearchViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchViewController") as! SearchViewController
   self.presentOnRoot(with: popup)


   extension UIViewController {
        func presentOnRoot(`with` viewController : UIViewController){
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
            navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
            self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this does seem to be a custom transition. You can achieve this by `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`

Here's a good tutorial to start with: [Raywenderlich: Custom VC Presentation tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2925473-ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions)

Once you understand the delegates and the animation controllers properly, you can write your own present/dismiss animation through the `containerView` provided.

One way to do this is to simply specify your desired frame through the `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView` variable on your `UIPresentationController` class and simply animate its presentation and dismissal through the containerView. Here's an example for the presentationController that I'm talking about:-

```
class YourPresentationController: UIPresentationController {

//Do whatever stuff you want to. I've added a view with black tint to emphasise presentation 

let dimmingView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
    return view
}()

override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
    dimmingView.frame = containerView!.bounds
    dimmingView.alpha = 0.0
    containerView!.insertSubview(dimmingView, at: 0)

    presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        self.dimmingView.alpha = 1.0
    })
}

override func dismissalTransitionWillBegin() {
    presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        self.dimmingView.alpha = 0.0
    }) { _ in
        self.dimmingView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

//This variable is what I'm talking about. Just specify the frame that you would want your presented VC's view to be at:-

override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
    var size = containerView!.bounds.size
    return CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: size) 
}

override func containerViewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    dimmingView.frame = containerView!.bounds
    presentedView?.frame = frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView
}
}
```

... and do a simple animation while presenting and dismissing the view(in the `containerView` of your `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` inherited class) to show that 'fade' effect. Also note that there are 'n' number of ways to do this and this is just one among them